# EnumCameraObjects in CameraRemote SDK returns Error code that has no definition (Error 1)

Tags: c++, enums, sdk, sony

```
#include <iostream>

#include <iomanip>

#include "../CRSDK/CameraRemote_SDK.h"

#include "Text.hpp"



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto init_success = SCRSDK::Init(); // SDK Initialization, works fine

    if (!init_success) {

        SDKTest::tout << "Failed to initialize Remote SDK. Terminating.\n";

        // cr_lib->Release();

        SCRSDK::Release();

        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    SDKTest::tout << "SDK successuflly initialized. \n\n";

    

    CrInt32u version = SCRSDK::GetSDKVersion();// Get SDK Version, works fine

    int major = (version & 0xFF000000) >> 24;

    int minor = (version & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;

    int patch = (version & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;

    

    SDKTest::tout << "Remote SDK version: ";

    SDKTest::tout << major << "." << minor << "." << std::setfill(TEXT('0')) << std::setw(2) << patch << "\n";

    

    SCRSDK::ICrEnumCameraObjectInfo* camera_list = nullptr;// List cameras connected, returns Error 1 when camera connected

    auto enum_status = SCRSDK::EnumCameraObjects(&camera_list);

    if (CR_FAILED(enum_status) || camera_list == nullptr) {

        SDKTest::tout << "Current Status: " << enum_status << "\n";

        SDKTest::tout << "No cameras detected. Connect a camera and retry.\n";

        // cr_lib->Release();

        SCRSDK::Release();

        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }

    SDKTest::tout << "Current Status:" << enum_status << "\n";

    SCRSDK::Release();

}
```

The above is my code for testing SONY CameraRemote SDK 1.3.0 using A7R4, and `Text.hpp` is from the source code in official sample app of CameraRemoteSDK, and my problem is when the camera is not connected, `SCRSDK::EnumCameraObjects` (the return type is `CrError`) returns 0 which means `CrError_None` and this is OK, however when I connected my A7R4, it returns Error 1, but in the definition of `CrError.h` there is no error or warning code 1, but the official sample app works normally, could anyone help with my problem? Thanks in advance!

below is the code of `CrError.h`

```
#ifndef _CRERROR_H_
#define _CRERROR_H_
#include "CrTypes.h"

namespace SCRSDK
{
    typedef CrInt32 CrError;
    enum
    {
        // 16bit    always 1
        // 9-15bit  category of error
        // 1-8bit   error detail in category
        CrError_None                                = 0x0000,
        CrError_Genric                              = 0x8000,
        CrError_File                                = 0x8100,
        CrError_Connect                             = 0x8200,
        CrError_Memory                              = 0x8300,
        CrError_Api                                 = 0x8400,
        CrError_Init                                = 0x8500,
        CrError_Polling                             = 0x8600,
        CrError_Adaptor                             = 0x8700,
        CrError_Device                              = 0x8800,

        CrError_Application                         = 0xc000,

        // Uncategorized
        CrError_Genric_Unknown                      = CrError_Genric,
        CrError_Genric_Notimpl,
        CrError_Genric_Abort,
        CrError_Genric_NotSupported,
        CrError_Genric_SeriousErrorNotSupported,
        CrError_Genric_InvalidHandle,
        CrError_Genric_InvalidParameter,

        // File related
        CrError_File_Unknown                        = CrError_File, 
        CrError_File_IllegalOperation,
        CrError_File_IllegalParameter,
        CrError_File_EOF,
        CrError_File_OutOfRange,
        CrError_File_NotFound,
        CrError_File_DirNotFound,
        CrError_File_AlreadyOpened,
        CrError_File_PermissionDenied,
        CrError_File_StorageFull,
        CrError_File_AlreadyExists,
        CrError_File_TooManyOpenedFiles,
        CrError_File_ReadOnly,
        CrError_File_CantOpen,
        CrError_File_CantClose,
        CrError_File_CantDelete,
        CrError_File_CantRead,
        CrError_File_CantWrite,
        CrError_File_CantCreateDir,
        CrError_File_OperationAbortedByUser,
        CrError_File_UnsupportedOperation,
        CrError_File_NotYetCompleted,
        CrError_File_Invalid,
        CrError_File_StorageNotExist,
        CrError_File_SharingViolation,
        CrError_File_Rotation,
        CrError_File_SameNameFull,

        // Connection related
        CrError_Connect_Unknown                     = CrError_Connect,
        CrError_Connect_Connect,
        CrError_Connect_Reserved1,
        CrError_Connect_Release,
        CrError_Connect_GetProperty,
        CrError_Connect_SendCommand,
        CrError_Connect_HandlePlugin,
        CrError_Connect_Disconnected,
        CrError_Connect_TimeOut,
        CrError_Reconnect_TimeOut,
        CrError_Connect_FailRejected,
        CrError_Connect_FailBusy,
        CrError_Connect_FailUnspecified,
        CrError_Connect_Cancel,

        //Memory related
        CrError_Memory_Unknown                      = CrError_Memory,
        CrError_Memory_OutOfMemory,
        CrError_Memory_InvalidPointer,
        CrError_Memory_Insufficient,

        //API related
        CrError_Api_Unknown                         = CrError_Api,
        CrError_Api_Insufficient,
        CrError_Api_InvalidCalled,

        CrError_Polling_Unknown                     = CrError_Polling,
        CrError_Polling_InvalidVal_Intervals,

        //Adaptor related
        CrError_Adaptor_Unknown                     = CrError_Adaptor,
        CrError_Adaptor_InvaildProperty,
        CrError_Adaptor_GetInfo,
        CrError_Adaptor_Create,
        CrError_Adaptor_SendCommand,
        CrError_Adaptor_HandlePlugin,
        CrError_Adaptor_CreateDevice,
        CrError_Adaptor_EnumDecvice,
        CrError_Adaptor_Reset,
        CrError_Adaptor_Read,
        CrError_Adaptor_Phase,
        CrError_Adaptor_DataToWiaItem,
        CrError_Adaptor_DeviceBusy,
        CrError_Adaptor_Escape,

        CrError_Device_Unknown                      = CrError_Device,

        CrWarning_Unknown                           = 0x00020000,
        CrWarning_Connect_Reconnected,
        CrWarning_Connect_Reconnecting,
        CrWarning_File_StorageFull,
        CrWarning_SetFileName_Failed,
        CrWarning_GetImage_Failed,
        CrWarning_FailedToSetCWB,
        CrWarning_NetworkErrorOccurred,
        CrWarning_NetworkErrorRecovered,
        CrWarning_Format_Failed,
        CrWarning_Format_Invalid,
        CrWarning_Format_Complete,
        CrWarning_Reserved1,
        CrWarning_Reserved2,
        CrWarning_Reserved3,
        CrWarning_Reserved4,
        CrWarning_Reserved5,
        CrWarning_Exposure_Started,
        CrWarning_DateTime_Setting_Result_Invalid,
        CrWarning_DateTime_Setting_Result_OK,
        CrWarning_DateTime_Setting_Result_Parameter_Error,
        CrWarning_DateTime_Setting_Result_Exclusion_Error,
        CrWarning_DateTime_Setting_Result_System_Error,
        CrWarning_Frame_NotUpdated,
        CrNotify_All_Download_Complete,
        CrWarning_Connect_Already,
        CrWarning_Connect_OverLimitOfDevice,
    };

    #define CR_SUCCEEDED(e) (SCRSDK::CrError_None == (e))
    #define CR_FAILED(e)    (SCRSDK::CrError_None != (e))
}

#endif //_CRERROR_H_
```

Comment: I see your problem. You initialize enum_status with EnumCameraObjects(&camera_list). Change the & into a *

Comment: It doesn't work, and will report error when compiling, the official sample app also uses `&` but it works.